# Why does Windows randomise the PEB and TEB?

Tags: windows, security, aslr

According to a [report by Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/avcenter/reference/Address_Space_Layout_Randomization.pdf):

> The address of an operating system structure known as the Process Environment Block (PEB) is also
>   selected randomly. The PEB randomization feature was introduced earlier in Windows XP SP2 and
>   Windows 2003 SP1, and is also present in Windows Vista. Although implemented separately, it is also
>   a form of address space randomization; but unlike the other ASLR features, PEB randomization occurs
>   whether or not the executable being loaded elected to use the ASLR feature.

When a process in Windows is to be randomised, the base addresses of the stack and the heap are randomised for obvious reasons.
But why is the PEB/TEB also being randomised what is the benefit here?

The way I see it, you want to randomise the base of the heap and the stack so that if an attacker gains the ability to execute shellcode on behalf of the process - you want to prevent that attacker from utilising some known pointers by randomising them. An attacker would get control over the IP, but he would not know where to jump to next.

But what is the point with the PEB? to access the PEB you have to go through the GDT by using the FS segment with code similar to this:

```
mov ax, fs:0x30
```

If the access to the PEB is already abstracted for you, when you gain code execution - you can directly access the PEB with a few instructions without having to worry about the actual address of the PEB which was randomised by ASLR.

So, what is the benefit of PEB randomization?

Comment: It makes it harder for an attacker from outside the process to modify the PEB. Modifying data a process is going to read and parse or otherwise process is often an avenue to ultimately have that process execute your code.

Comment: It makes the PEB harder to find for attackers who do not have code execution.

Comment: @IInspectable, the PEB and TEB addresses can be queried from another process via `NtQueryInformationProcess`: `ProcessBasicInformation` and `NtQueryInformationThread`: `ThreadBasicInformation`. These calls require only limited-query access, so another process in the session can usually obtain this information. For example, CMD's internal `GetProcessSubsystemTypeFromAddressSpace` function queries the PEB of a child process and tries to read the image header in order to determine whether it's a console process with which it should synchronize.

Comment: @ery: *"[NtQueryInformationProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess) may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows."* If Microsoft discovers vulnerabilities due to software modifying the PEB, they could change this API to not return a pointer to the PEB, or pull the plug and remove it altogether. As it currently stands, it's hard to see how randomizing the PEB address provides any sort of protection, when the system just passes out the randomized address when asked for it.

Comment: @IInspectable, a process can be created with or modify its DACL to prevent opening it with limited-query or VM read/write access, or set its mandatory label in the SACL to deny read-up access from a lower integrity level. Administrators can still get at least limited-query access via SeDebugPrivilege -- as well as the right to actually read the PEB via `ReadProcessMemory`, though in some cases that may require the extra step of impersonating the access token of a SYSTEM process.

Comment: @IInspectable, as to the likelihood of changing the `ProcessBasicInformation` query, I'd put that at just slightly above 0. This call is fundamental to the system. That would be a very expensive change to make. Security on getting the required access to a process could be locked down tighter, however.